# Проблемы использования установленного yii2-simplechat и yii2-twig

Tags: yii2, composer, модули

У меня проблема следующего толка. Я установил yii2-simplechat через composer на yii2 basic по инструкции: https://github.com/bubasuma/yii2-simplechat . Добавил "bubasuma/yii2-simplechat": "*" в composer.json и запустил composer update. Всё легло хорошо. Но это simplechat не работал через yii2-twig. Я его тоже установил через composer по следующей инструкции: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-twig . Всё легло и установилось хорошо. Но при выходе на страницу http://premium-my-freestyle.esy.es/messages чтобы посмотреть как заработал чат показывается следующее сообщение:
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The file or directory to be published does not exist: /home/u172121359/vendor/bower/twig.js") .
Вот картинка ошибки:
[image: Картинка ошибки] 
Что там может быть не так? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.
Уточните, какой именно версии у Вас yii2?
Посмотрите, что именно находится по пути vendor/bower?
Возможно директория называется bower-access?
Если она называется именно bower-access, то в конфигурационном файле укажите псевдонимы

```
'aliases' => [
    '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
    '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
],
```

Comment: Версия Yii 2.0.15.1 .Я добавил то что Вы написали. Только папка называется bower (просто). npm там вообще нет. А он нужен?

Comment: Всё равно это не помогло.

Comment: В ошибке же говорится, что "при создании шаблона было выбрано исключение
файл или каталог, который будет опубликован, не существует".  Проверяйте все пути, возможно что-то забыли указать.

Comment: И зачем Вы добавляли псевдонимы, если директория у Вас называется bower?

Comment: Я понял чтобы решить эту проблему нужно прописать в composer.json

Comment: Я понял чтобы решить эту проблему нужно прописать в composer.json : "require": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-twig": "> 2.0.4",
        "bower-asset/twig.js" : "0.8.4@stable"
    }, Как здесь: https://github.com/bubasuma/yii2-simplechat/wiki/Using-twig-as-template-engine. Но дело в том, что при composer update появляется надпись "The requested package bower-asset/twig.js could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name". То есть не устанавливается twig.js . Как быть?

Comment: но у Вас же по другому называется директория bower-asset

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75575/discussion-between-tchprogrammer-and-slo-nik).

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня долго не устанавливался twig.js ("bower-asset/twig.js": "0.8.4@stable"). Но я решил эту проблему тем что установил composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1". Далее twig.js установился как надо. Но когда я выхожу на страницу premium-my-freestyle.esy.es/… выходит то же самое сообщение "The file or directory to be published does not exist: /home/u172121359/vendor/bower/twig.js". А теперь-то почему? (Я тот же вопрос задал в чате).

Comment: composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.4.1"

Answer (score 0):

Я решил данную задачу. Вот комплекс мероприятий, которые я сделал:
1) Установил asset-менеджер fxp/composer-asset-plugin (в секции require composer.json прописал:"fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "v1.1.4"). Или composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1" . Без него ничего работать не будет, twig.js не установится. Также установил другие пакеты:

```
"yiisoft/yii2-twig": "dev-master",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",
    "bower-asset/twig.js": "0.8.4@stable",
    "bubasuma/yii2-simplechat": "*"
```

Это всё в секции require.
Далее прописал в файле конфига альясы (у меня config/web.php):

```
'aliases' => [
    '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
    //'@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
],
```

И всё заработало.